# How to merge two dynamic array of objects into a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops, object

Step 1: LANDING PAGE

I have one list of array of objects. Which is created dynamically by pushing objects in array i:e listA. So this array can have different length's as per the selection of objects. For e.g here I selected 3 objects

```
listA: any[] = [{name:"james", mailAddress: "james@dd.com", addr: "xyz 123 block"},
                {name:"eden", mailAddress: "eden@dd.com", addr: "xyz 456 block"},
                {name:"rock", mailAddress: "rock@dd.com", addr: "xyz 789 block"}]
```

I also stored this listA in session Storage like this for later use

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("listA", JSON.stringify(listA));
```

Step 2: NEXT PAGE

Now in step two using some input fields for each row of listA I changed email values in each object and stored that in listB. For e.g

```
listA = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('listA'));
listA: any[] = [{name:"james", mailAddress: "jack@dd.com", addr: "xyz 123 block"},
                {name:"eden", mailAddress: "zeus@dd.com", addr: "xyz 456 block"},
                {name:"rock", mailAddress: "stone@dd.com", addr: "xyz 789 block"}]
```

I also stored this updated listA in session Storage under a new name listB like this for later use

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("listB", JSON.stringify(listB));
```

Step 3: SUBMIT PAGE

Now in final step I need to submit a request and merge the objects like this

```
    finalList: any[] = [{name:"james", oldmailAddress: "james@dd.com", newmailAddress: "jack@dd.com" addr: "xyz 123 block", country: "hungry", state: ""},
                        {name:"eden", oldmailAddress: "eden@dd.com", newmailAddress: "zeus@dd.com", addr: "xyz 456 block", country: "spain", state: ""},
                        {name:"rock", oldmailAddress: "rock@dd.com", newmailAddress: "stone@dd.com", addr: "xyz 789 block", country: "", state: "new york"}]
```

Remember I have both the lists available with me in session storage as listA, listB

What I tried till now.

```
submit() {
  let requestObj: any;
  let listA = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('listA'));
  let listB = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('listB'));
  let finalObjsArr: any[] = [];

  listA.forEach((el: any) => {
    // And the other values also but for display purpose not adding the other keys....
    requestObj.oldmailAddress = el.mailAddress;        
    finalObjsArr.push(requestObj)
  })

  finalObjArr.forEach((objf: any) => {
   listB.forEach((el: any) => {
     // And the other values also but for display purpose not adding the other keys....
     objf.newmailAddress = el.mailAddress;
   }
  }

  console.log(finalObjsArr);  
}
```

But this will result in wrong length of array list . So suppose I select 3 objects I will get 9 objects back in final list that also with wrong values.

I tried few other ways also but the result is same

Required -- Here I have to take values from one array of object and update the request object then again I have to take another list of array and insert values in previously created array and create the final request object array with both old and new values. So basically merging two arrays of objects adding old and new values for each object.

I know this technique is wrong. Is there any other work around for this?

Comment: To start with, there's no such thing as `foreach`, you'll need to use `forEach` to avoid a TypeError

Comment: That's typo mistakes. I think everyone know what is foreach loop

Comment: Make sure to copy your code *exactly* - typo mistakes are often cause for closure of a question, so make sure a question is free of typos before posting

Comment: Updated thanks for letting me know that

Comment: From where `country` and `state` come from? They aren't inside any of list.

Comment: Yes but they will be included in final request from initial response from backend. You can ignore those keys

Comment: Which field is unique (how do you know that two of them needs to be merged)?

Comment: There will be no unique keys. Final request array will be like this as shown in example. I need to create a unique array out of two similar arrays with old and new value for any key updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array `.map` javascript:

```
const listA = [{name:"james", mailAddress: "james@dd.com", addr: "xyz 123 block"},
                {name:"eden", mailAddress: "eden@dd.com", addr: "xyz 456 block"},
                {name:"rock", mailAddress: "rock@dd.com", addr: "xyz 789 block"}]
```

If array `listB` is assumed to be this way

```
const listB = [{name:"james", mailAddress: "jack@dd.com", addr: "xyz 123 block", country: "hungry", state: ""},
                        {name:"eden", mailAddress: "zeus@dd.com", addr: "xyz 456 block", country: "spain", state: ""},
                        {name:"rock", mailAddress: "stone@dd.com", addr: "xyz 789 block", country: "", state: "new york"}]
```

The final array will be obtained as follows:

```
const finalList = listB.map(({mailAddress, ...otherItems}, idx) => {
    return({
        ...otherItems,
        oldmailAddress: listA[idx].mailAddress,
        newmailAddress: mailAddress,
    })
})

console.log(finalList)
```

Comment: Thanks..this technique worked for me. Though I had to make a new unique array of objects. But through this code I was able to achieve what was required. Many thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
const listA = [{name:"james", mailAddress: "james@dd.com", addr: "xyz 123 block"},
               {name:"eden", mailAddress: "eden@dd.com", addr: "xyz 456 block"},
               {name:"rock", mailAddress: "rock@dd.com", addr: "xyz 789 block"}]

const listB = [{name:"james", mailAddress: "jack@dd.com", addr: "xyz 123 block"},
               {name:"eden", mailAddress: "zeus@dd.com", addr: "xyz 456 block"},
               {name:"rock", mailAddress: "stone@dd.com", addr: "xyz 789 block"}]

const mergeAndUpdate = (oldArr, newArr) =>
    newArr.map((e, i) => ({
        oldMailAddress: oldArr[i].mailAddress,
        newMailAddress: e.mailAddress,
        name: e.name,
        addr: e.addr
    }))

console.log(mergeAndUpdate(listA, listB))
```